# Phoenix in Action (final edition): Jason error

Tags: phoenix-framework

I'm having the same problem as this [github issue](https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/issues/3206).

On p. 110, the final version of `Phoenix in Action 1.4` says,

> You need to do one more thing before you can start up the server.
>   Phoenix requires you to let it know which library you’d like it to use
>   when processing data in JSON format. The default library that Phoenix
>   uses is called Jason, and it’s what you’ll use as well. In the top
>   level of your umbrella application, you need to configure the Phoenix
>   dependency to use Jason. In `auction_umbrella/config/config.exs`, add
>   the last line in the following listing:
>
> ```
> use Mix.Config
> import_config "../apps/*/config/config.exs"
> config :phoenix, :json_library, Jason
> ```

I did that, but when I cd into the `apps/auction_web` dir, and try to start the server:

```
$ iex -S mix phx.server
```

I get the error:

```
Erlang/OTP 20 [erts-9.3] [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [ds:4:4:10] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]

warning: failed to load Jason for Phoenix JSON encoding
(module Jason is not available).

Ensure Jason exists in your deps in mix.exs,
and you have configured Phoenix to use it for JSON encoding by
verifying the following exists in your config/config.exs:

    config :phoenix, :json_library, Jason


  (phoenix) lib/phoenix.ex:40: Phoenix.start/2
  (kernel) application_master.erl:273: :application_master.start_it_old/4

Compiling 11 files (.ex)

== Compilation error in file lib/auction_web/endpoint.ex ==
** (ArgumentError) invalid :json_decoder option. The module Poison is not loaded and could not be found
    (plug) lib/plug/parsers/json.ex:54: Plug.Parsers.JSON.validate_decoder!/1
    (plug) lib/plug/parsers/json.ex:32: Plug.Parsers.JSON.init/1
    (plug) lib/plug/parsers.ex:245: anonymous fn/3 in Plug.Parsers.convert_parsers/2
    (elixir) lib/enum.ex:1899: Enum."-reduce/3-lists^foldl/2-0-"/3
    (plug) lib/plug/parsers.ex:228: Plug.Parsers.convert_parsers/2
    (plug) lib/plug/parsers.ex:224: Plug.Parsers.init/1
    (plug) lib/plug/builder.ex:302: Plug.Builder.init_module_plug/4
    (plug) lib/plug/builder.ex:286: anonymous fn/5 in Plug.Builder.compile/3
~/phoenix_apps/auction_umbrella/apps/auction_web$
```

Other info:

```
$ mix phx.new --version
Phoenix v1.4.0
```

Then I tried adding the `jason` dependency to both the mix.exs file for the umbrella app as well as the mix.exs file for the auction_web app, then I did `mix deps.get` in both directories containing the mix.exs file, and I still get the same error when I try to start the server.

Answer (score 0):

Aargh!  I mis-typed `phoneix` (should be `phoenix`) in the config file.

Then, I deleted the :jason dependencies from both mix.exs files, then I did `mix deps.get` (to rewrite the lock files), then `mix deps.clean jason`, and when I tried to start the server I got the same error.

So, to which mix.exs file should I add the :jason dependency?  I added the :jason dependency to the auction_web mix.exs file, then did `mix deps.get`, then the server started.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're followup answer states that you figured it out, but you add the dependency configuration to `auction_umbrella/config/config.exs`.

> I added the :jason dependency to the auction_web mix.exs file, then did mix deps.get, then the server started.

Does this mean everything is working for you now?

Comment: Hey author!  Thanks for taking a look.  Everything is working for me.  I even created a second project to verify whether I needed to manually add the `:jason` dependency; and if I had not mispelled `phoenix` in the config file, then everything would have worked as written in the book because the `mix phx.new.web auction_web` command automatically enters the `:jason` dependency in the auction_web mix.exs file under `deps`.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for responding back. I'm glad everything worked out as written.